# VFIO: PCI-stub GPU passthrough only audio device

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, kubuntu, 17.04

I'm in desperate need of help as I have tried everything I can imagine.

I'm trying to setup GPU passthrough. It works perfect on Nouveau drivers and both my GPU and Audio gets stubbed. 
However I'm forced to use NVIDIA drivers due to having a GTX1050 card as 'main' card (using a gTX980 as passthrough). 
On Nouveau drivers only 1 screen works on a very small resolution and I'm unable to fix this.

But the main problem is, is that only 1 device, the audio gets stubbed:

```
# dmesg | grep stub
[    2.015410] pci-stub: add 10DE:13C0 sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF 
cls=00000000/00000000
[    2.015413] pci-stub: add 10DE:0FBB sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF 
cls=00000000/00000000
[    2.015420] pci-stub 0000:02:00.1: claimed by stub
```

So as far as I get it, NVIDIA claims the device before PCI-stub gets the chance.
I don't know how to fix it. Is anyone able to help me out?

Using Kubuntu 17.04 on a GTX1050, trying to passthrough a GTX980 with NVIDIA 381.22 drivers.

Let me know if any further information is required, thank you!